# Cusps and intersection multiplicities (Fulton 3.22)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Could anyone help with (c)? I have written up some of my solutions that I'm unsure whether is right.

**Problem:**
Suppose $P$ is a double point on a curve $F$, and suppose $F$ has only one tangent line $L$ at $P$.

(a) Show that $I(P, F\cap L) \geq 3$. The curve $F$ is said to have a cusp at $P$ if
$I(P, F \cap L) = 3$.

(b) Suppose $P = (0,0)$ and $L=y$. Show that $P$ is a cusp if and only if $F_{xxx} (P) \neq 0$.

(c) Show that if $P$ is a cusp on $F$, then $F$ has only one component passing through $P$.

**Ideas:**
For (b), since $TC_P V(f) = V(L)$ and as $L$ is a line through $P=(0,0)$ we have
$TC_P V(L) = V(L)$. But as $f_{xxx} (P) \neq 0$, we have
that if we write $f_3 = a x^3 + b x^2 y + c x y^2 + d y^3$ then $a \neq 0$, so
$mult_P (f(x,0)) \leq 3$ hence by (a),
$mult_P(f(x,0)) = 3$, so as $mult_P (L) = 1$, and as $TC_P V(f(x,0)) \not \supset V(y)$, we have $I_P(f(x,0), L) = mult_P (f(x,0)) mult_P(L) = 3$.